# STM32F4 HAL SPI TransmitReceive DMA Rx buffer being written to Tx buffer

Tags: c++, stm32, spi, dma

I am communicating between an STM32F4 (master) and an SPI device (slave).
Communicating has been established I am debugging everything with a logic analyzer.

Datasize is set to 8 bit and I am transmitting and receiving 4x 8-bit words.
Clock is set to /8 prescaler (roughly 5MHz in my case).

My Rx/Tx buffers are declared (Tx buffer is fixed):

```
uint8_t spi_dma_tx_[4] = {0xB2, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
uint8_t spi_dma_rx_[4] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
```

After setting CS pin low, I am using this to initiate transfer:

```
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(spi_cs_port_, spi_cs_pin_, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive_DMA(hw_config_.spi, (uint8_t*)spi_dma_tx_, (uint8_t*)spi_dma_rx_, 4);
```

Data from the SPI device is processed after this call back:

```
void HAL_SPI_TxRxCpltCallback(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi) {
    tero->prd_.spi_cb();
}
```

which does something like this:

```
void prd::spi_cb() {
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(spi_cs_port_, spi_cs_pin_, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    //data reconstruction using stuff in spi_dma_rx[]
    ../.. //sparing you the details here
}
```

In summary, once spi_dma_tx[] is declared, it's never played with.
Data in spi_dma_rx[] is extracted for reconstruction inside the spi callback function.

What I see on the logic analyzer is puzzling me:

On MOSI: 0xB2, 0x00, 0xB2, 0xCA
on MISO: 0xB2, 0xCA, 0x17, 0xBE (the 3 bytes following 0xB2 are actual data, which will change all the time, 0xB2 is confirmation that the command has been properly understood by the device - i.e. no problem on MISO)

Notes:

Everything on MISO is as expected and the device seems to be working as intended.
On MOSI however, I should have: 0xB2, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 - nothing else, it should be that ALL the time. (MISO output 0xB2 on the first byte is also normal, as confirmation the command was received properly).
However, the first 2 bytes on MISO are systematically copied to third and fourth byte of MOSI, systematically.

Has anyone ever seen anything like this?

I would really like to understand what's going on. Searched through my entire project and literally spi_dma_tx is never called anywhere outside of the variable declaration and the HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive_DMA(..) function.

Cheers

Comment: It's called buffer overflow. Provider that spi_dma_tx is your MOSI message. Check your memory map if spi_dma_tx is allocated just after spi_dma_rx_. Use a watchpoint to break on all writes to spi_dma_tx. Are you sure that the fourth parameter of HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive_DMA is valid on both transmission and reception? Check the omitted routine after reception.